# XmlHolder VS GroovyUtil.getXmlHolder

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing, soapui

When we can create xmlholder instace with its consturctor  XmlHolder(String xml) ie. using code

```
 def holder= new XmlHolder(context.expand('${Login#request}')
```

why do we use GroovyUtils  class to create xmlholder object as mentioned below..is it code performance

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("GetUserTypes#ResponseAsXml")
```

Comment: Is the answer helpful? are you looking for something more?

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid. It is matter of flexibility.

`XmlHolder` is an independent class and it can be used directly to create an instance.

Where as `GroovyUtil` class has a static method to get the `XmlHolder`.